# Formula: PERCENTRANK IF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, percentile

I have a date column and a column that states "Include" or "Don't Include." I want to calculate the Percentile of each row in my data set given that they are marked to be included.  Any thoughts on how to group them?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please share some sample data (you can use dummy values if it's private) and give us a sense of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

@RCarmody try:

```
=IF(B2="Included",COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,"Included")/COUNTA($B$2:$B$11),"")
```

Output:
[image]